# PHP MYSQL SUM Until a row then stop

Tags: php, mysql, sum, case

Basically I am creating a sort of checking account type query.
Which would be fairly easy except I want it split into pages.

So I have a field that is called `amount` and it can be a positive or a negative number.

The problem is if I am on records 75-100 I need to have a query sum all of `amount` up until record 75 and give me the total. 
Then I can run my query for records 75-100 and loop through their amounts like so:
(supposing that the sum up to and including 74 was $500)

```
record#    Amount    Total
75         25.00     525.00
76         35.00     560.00
77         40.00     600.00

etc.
```

What I was thinking was to get the idnum for record 75 and sum up until it finds it like so:
    SUM(case when `idnum` != $until then `amount` else 0 end)

However this just keeps going. It doesn't stop at 75 it just skips 75 then sums 76, 77, etc..
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `record` always sequential for each account or can there be gaps in the sequence?

Comment: SELECT SUM(amount) AS amt FROM table ..... rest of query

Comment: do you want to get sum of id from 1 to 75 or sum of total 75 records?

Comment: Hi, Joachim there will be gaps in the sequence.  Punk, that would just get me the entire SUM, and it misses the point.Yadav, if I understand you right, it is the sum of 1-75 with a WHERE that will pick only certain ones out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @total=0;
SELECT
     recordno, 
     amount,    
     @total:= @total+ amount AS total
FROM table1 
LIMIT 75, 75
```

or

```
SELECT 
      cur.id, cur.amount, sum(prev.amount)
FROM table1 cur
left join table1 prev
    on cur.id >= prev.id
group by cur.id 
LIMIT 75, 75
```

here limit function start records from 76 to another 75 records, you can send this as parameter

Comment: How and where do I add: `WHERE group = '35'`

Comment: is there column named group in your table? have you try to write where clause with above solutions?

Comment: yes there is a column named group.  where do I added that where?  thanks

Comment: Oh I figured it out, it needs to have cur.group = '35'

Comment: Sorry to bug you again I instead decided to use your first option above with `SET @total=0;` but that is causing my loop issues. Here is my actual code" `$result2 = mysql_query("SET @total=0;
SELECT *,
@total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
FROM `recordedhours` WHERE `group` = '$uid'
ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC, `idnum` DESC
LIMIT $from, $max_results"); while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {  //do stuff   }`  but I get the error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...`

Comment: @topedge you better ask new question for that

Comment: Okay here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128462/php-mysql-set-gives-error-in-while-loop