# PHP MYSQL SET gives error in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, set

I have this query:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SET @total=0;
SELECT *,
@total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
FROM `recordedhours` WHERE `group` = '$uid'
ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC, `idnum` DESC
LIMIT $from, $max_results");

while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
//DO STUFF
}
```

But the SET @total=0; makes the while line give me an error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
The query works fine in phpmyadmin and the while works fine without the SET @total=0;

Comment: You can't give multiple queries in a call to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Look @ http://stackoverflow.com/q/12274964/1288198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can not use more than one queries in `mysql_query()`, But you can combine both your query into a single one.

Try this query..

```
SELECT *,
@total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
FROM `recordedhours`, (SELECT @total:=0) r WHERE `group` = '$uid'
ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC, `idnum` DESC
LIMIT $from, $max_results
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that worked for that issue but it is not giving the proper results when listed.  I am trying to list two numbers.  The companyearned and the total as it goes.  And it should have the oldest results on the bottom.  That is working fine for the companyearned,  but total is going in the reverse order.  This this is what I am getting: `$-23.22 $-23.22; 
$-20.22 $-43.44;
$300.00 $256.56; 
$-6.00 $250.56;`   and this is what I want: `$-23.22 $181.20; 
$-20.22 $204.42;
$300.00 $224.64;
$-6.00 -75.36; (which has brought in the total from all pages up until this point)`

Comment: any ideas what I can do to change this?

Comment: I decided since this is in addition to what I was doing it needed it's own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173444/php-mysql-sum-total-but-show-rows

Answer (score 0):

Use two calls to `mysql_query()`:

```
mysql_query("SET @total=0");

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,
@total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
FROM `recordedhours` WHERE `group` = '$uid'
ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC, `idnum` DESC
LIMIT $from, $max_results");
```

I think the variable should persist since it's the same database connection.

Comment: it should be `mysql_query("SET GLOBAL @total=0");`

Comment: @Amir This is just a session variable. Only users with the SUPER permission can set global variables.