# PHP MYSQL SUM total but show rows

Tags: php, mysql, sum

What I am trying to do is display earning by the page showing the last entries on top.
But it still needs to get the total up to each row.

So page one might look like this:

```
Date      Amount    Balance
1/9/2013   10.00    80.00
1/7/2013   10.00    70.00
1/6/2013   10.00    60.00
```

Page 2 might look like this:

```
Date      Amount    Balance
1/5/2013   10.00    50.00
1/4/2013   10.00    40.00
1/3/2013   10.00    30.00
1/2/2013   10.00    20.00
1/1/2013   10.00    10.00
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
Date      Amount    Balance
1/9/2013   10.00    60.00
1/7/2013   10.00    70.00
1/6/2013   10.00    80.00
```

Page 2 looks like this:

```
Date      Amount    Balance
1/5/2013   10.00    10.00
1/4/2013   10.00    20.00
1/3/2013   10.00    30.00
1/2/2013   10.00    40.00
1/1/2013   10.00    50.00
```

Notice that the balances are backward.  But even though my example doesn't show it, the amounts are in the right order.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT *,
@total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
FROM `recordedhours`, (SELECT @total:=0) r WHERE `group` = '$uid'
ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC, `idnum` DESC
LIMIT $from, $max_results

 while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
//CREATE ROWS HERE
}
```

Your help is very much appreciated!  :)

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY unixdate ASC`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Yes that puts it in the wrong order.  Even making the 1st page the first results.  This would be very anoying for someone to find the last entry to have to go to the last page.  I want it displayed much like the way paypal does the history

Comment: @topedge.. look @ my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `SQL`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, @total:= @total+ `companyearned` AS `total`
    FROM `recordedhours`, (SELECT @total:=0) r WHERE `group` = '$uid'
    ORDER BY `unixdate` ASC, `idnum` DESC
    LIMIT $from, $max_results
) tab ORDER BY `unixdate` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but that really messed things up.  Including it switched the page order.  And it is now only summing each page not up to the page I am on.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast, I added it above by editing your suggestion since comments do not allow us to show columns and rows.

Comment: hmmm, it looks like my edit was removed.  Well here is what this solution did: it reversed the order of everything.  So the old orders were first and on the first page.  It also only did a sum for the page that it was on.

Comment: do you have any other ideas?